# What is inside Batman's ears?

Tags: dc, batman

This picture shows Batman missing an ear from his costume.

[image: Batman with right bat ear missing]

Which made me think, what does he keep inside his ears?

- Radio receiver to listen to police broadcasts?
- Radio connection back to Batmobile or to the Batcave?
- Super-sensitive sound sensors?
- Hidden weapons?
- Tiny little cameras?

Accepting answers from official sources.

Comment: I'm assuming that the correct answer is *"earwax, just like the rest of us"*

Comment: Bat-Wax! [Clearly labelled](https://kotaku.com/the-lego-classic-tv-series-batcave-has-all-the-60s-batm-1752465890), of course.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Only YOU can help Batman remove his ear polyps; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GoKJcG47Aq4

Comment: "*what does he keep inside his ears?*"  As shown in the @Valorum answer... anything the plot requires him to keep in there!!

Comment: To me, it looks like the ear is tilted backwards, not missing

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It depends on the continuity, but it's typically a set of directional microphones and high-gain antennas to give him *better-than-human* hearing abilities. Because he's a bat, see?

[image: tech inside the Bat cowl]

The prop from [*Dawn of Justice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_v_Superman:_Dawn_of_Justice) contains similar technology, according to the [*DoJ: Tech Manual*](https://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_v_Superman:_Dawn_of_Justice_Tech_Manual), describing the cowl as containing a

> titanium core and a range of infrared and sonic comms

[image: prop picture from different angles]

In [*All Star Batman* #2](https://dc.wikia.com/wiki/All-Star_Batman_Vol_1_2), we see that Batman's new cowl has ears that contain a little surprise, functioning as *the handles of a pair of concealed knives*

[image: Batlan stabs with ear-knives]

And in [*Batman and Robin* #22](https://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_and_Robin_Vol_1_22), the ears can be ejected and work as thrown knives.

[image: ears are ejected]

Comment: +1 for the first image. BTW, Batman's cowl also has an anti-imbalance system to fight with Count Vertigo.

Answer (score -3):

Yeah, Batman's ears contain high-gain radio antennas which Batman uses to:

- stay in contact with Alfred, Robin and Batgirl.
- listen police radio broadcast.

It was shown in *Batman: Detective Comics #741*.

[image: Batman calling Oracle]

Comment: Not to pick, but this panel doesn't show that his bat-ears contain a high gain antenna